# Distance from a point to a line, without the line extending to infinity

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose I have two lines which look sort of like this:

```
         C
         x
        /
A    B /
x----x/

   x
   D
```

One line is AB and the other is BC, the x's are points and D is an external point. If I compute the normal distance from D to AB and BC [as shown here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_passing_through_two_points), I get that D is closer to BC, rather than AB.

What I want is a way to compute the distance to a line, but without the line "extending" outside of the points that define it. How can I do that ?

Edit:
If you can also tell me how to get the point that is the closest on that line, it would be even better.

Comment: There are many sets of code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)  I didn't see any that explained how they work.

Comment: Do mean that you want to find the distance between $D$ and nearest point to $D$ of the segment $ \bar {BC}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a *parametrization* of the two lines. For example, you can define the two *line segments* between $A,B$ and $B,C$ by

$$r_1 = a + u(b-a)$$ and $$r_2 = b + v(c-b).$$

Any point on the line segments have values $u$ and $v$ in the interval $[0,1]$. So, when you calculate the closest point on $r_1$ to $D$ and the closest point on $r_2$ to $D$ you need to look out for the $u$ or $v$ value within the interval $[0,1]$. The line with $u$ or $v$ value outside this range is not the closest line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the distance from D to segment $\overline{BC}$

Find the point on line BC closest to D
Express that point as $\lambda B + (1-\lambda)C$
If $0 \le \lambda \le 1$ the distance is the distance from D to the line BC
If $\lambda \lt 0$ the closest point on the segment is B and the distance is DB
If $\lambda \gt 1$ the closest point on the segment is C and the distance is DC

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Cartesian_coordinates) gives the point on BC in the first section.  You need to convert the equation of the line from two point form to $ax+by+c=0$ form to use that directly